# working with ajax and php as front and backend

Tags: php, ajax

```
    var insertValue= $.ajax({
      url: "handle.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: text,
      dataType: "text"
    });         
    insertGroupData.done(function(msg){
      alert(msg);
    });
```

This is the first half, I'm stuck in the 1st line of my backend.php

I think it should be catch the POST value, but what should I catch?

```
<?php     
    if(isset($_POST["_____??_____"])){
     echo "test";
   }
```

Comment: We dont know whats in your POST because you didnt show us your form

Comment: look at var_dump($_POST)

Answer (score 2):

Jquery: if your data should be like

```
data: {test:text},
```

Then in  PHP you can use to get like below,

```
if(isset($_POST["test"])){
   echo "test";
}
```

**Explanation about data**:

Type: PlainObject or String

Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting .

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

change your code to this

```
    var insertValue= $.ajax({
          url: "handle.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: {text:text},
          dataType: "text"
        });
```

in backend page you can check it like

```
echo $_REQUEST['text];
```

or

```
echo $_POST['text];
```

Answer (score 0):

A lesson in jQuery

```
$(function () {
  var
    url = 'your/target/script.php',
    data,
    fn = function (text) {alert(text);},
    // fn will expect text, so set return as text
    dataType = 'text';
  // this POST data will populate $_POST as $_POST[key] = 'value'
  data = {
    ajax : 1,
    key : 'value',
    key2 : 'another value'
  };
  // shorthand notation is convenient sometimes
  $.post(url,data,fn,dataType);
});
```

Your php now has access to your key value pairs

```
<?php
// in my example the 3 are set
if (isset($_POST['ajax'])) {
  $_POST['key'];
  $_POST['key2'];
}
```

Happy coding